# Can you use Precise repos in Raring?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, repository

Is it possible to use Precise repositories in Raring?

Comment: It is possible, raring is EOF, though. But, when you add the precise repos, it will upgrade all of your packages to the precise version. Meaning it will turn raring into precise.

Comment: Will Ubuntu still work fine though?

Comment: I have never tried this. But, I have heard some success stories. However, I do advice you to upgrade to the latest [LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) version. Which is - At the time of writing - Ubuntu Trusty Tahr, 14.04.

Comment: 14.04 won't work on my PC and I found a raring livedvd lying around so I decided to try it out and it worked. I don't have time to download Precise at the moment since I'm not at home right now. I'm kind of curious about what would happen. Thanks, I'll see if this will work.

Comment: @piplupturtwig I would advice to try and find out why 14.04 does not work (we could help with that). The installer itself should be sort of the same between 12.04 and 14.04.

Comment: I posted a thread about this at the Ubuntu Forums. Here's the link,  [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297866)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that will not be possible for the simple fact that there are no 13.04 repositories anymore. There is the archive but those are not supported as a valid installation procedure. That would mean you need to manually download the package and add it to your system.

Now if you would do that with 2 current releases then yes it is possible to mix the 2 releases: you can add a PPA for that specific software you need and can then specify what release should be used.

In Software&Updates you can do this:

[image]

This is often done to get the latest apache, mysql, browsers and sometimes to get a bug fixed when it got fixed in a newer release.